# How to append element in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new for Angular, What i need?

```
<div class="parentClass">
     <div class="childclass1">
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <div class="childclass2">
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     <div class="childclass3">
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

i am using angular2 ngfor :

In Html file :

```
<div class="parentClass">
    <div *ngFor="let group of result;let i = index"  [innerHTML]="clearfix">
         <div class="childclass{{i}}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In component file :

```
clearfix:string = '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
```

Please help me.

Comment: What's the problem or the question? What is the actual and expected behavior?

Comment: I want to append this line '<div class="clearfix"></div>' for every childclass end.

Comment: What does "append" mean exactly. Do you want to add it statically or depending on a condition? What is `[innerHTML]="..."` for? Why don't you add it statically?

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template

Comment: Add that one line ( <div class="clearfix"></div> ) on dynamically.

Comment: <div class="parentClass">
    <div *ngFor="let group of result;let i = index"  [innerHTML]="clearfix">
         <div class="childclass{{i}}"></div>
    </div>
</div>

When i try the above code, i got this result : 

<div class="parentClass">
     <div class="childclass1">
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="childclass2">
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="childclass3">
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) use innerHTML. The HTML belongs to the template, not to the TypeScript code.

All you need is

```
<div class="parentClass">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of result; index as i"> 
      <div class="childclass{{ i + 1 }}"></div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. you save my day. Thanks lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the problem is you ask a solution for, but my guess is

```
<div class="parentClass">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let group of result;let i = index">
    <div class="childclass{{i}}"></div>
    <div [innerHTML]="clearfix"></div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```